# Java:How to align JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have this code but it doesn't work:

```
jPanel1.add(jLabel1);
jPanel2.add(jButton1);
jPanel2.add(jButton2);
jPanel3.add(jPanel1,jPanel1.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
jPanel3.add(jPanel2,jPanel2.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
setContentPane(jPanel3);

pack();
```

Please tell me why!

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: We could probably provide even more help (with code snippets) if you could show what exact visual layout you would like for your panel.

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting a LayoutManager on any of the panels.  This [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) may be of use to you

Comment: Thank's a lot! It realy helped me!

Comment: @John: Please consider accepting and/or up-voting this answer.